# basic concept about edge graphs (line graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was learning about the edge graphs or line graphs $L(G)$ of a graph $G$. I read about the relation between degree of any two vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$ and that of edge $uv$ in $L(G)$. I am just anxious to know is there any relation between the eccentricity of vertices of these two graphs? Any help or suggestion is welcomed. Any link to study in detail about line graphs?

Comment: Can you specify more on what you want to know?

Comment: @monalisa: Check out www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/705364.pdf where you will find the book "Graph Theory" by Harary. Chapter 8 of the book deals with "Line Graphs".

Comment: Consider that a walk of length $n$ in $G$ given by vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3\ldots,v_n$ gives a walk in $L(G)$ of length $n - 1$ ($v_1v_2,v_2v_3,\ldots,v_{n-1}v_n$). Likewise a walk of length $n - 1$ in $L(G)$ gives a walk of length $n$ in $G$. This sounds like a question I would put on a homework assignment, so I don't want to provide an answer outright, but I hope that helps!